# Last occurrence of foreign key in reference table mysql

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

I have two tables: return, and return_details

Return is setup like so -

```
 + Return
      - id
      - orderNum
      - startDate
      - endDate

 + Return_Details
      - id
      - rid (Return.id)
      - stage [this is essentially location]
      - lastSeen [timeDate last seen)
```

I am attempting to find all returns that are "open" (where Return.endDate == null) and then the `stage` and `lastSeen` for each open `Return.id`.

The problem is I can't figure out how to find the last occurrence of Return.id in Return_Details.  Currently I am able to find the correct lastSeen time using MAX but how do I grab the corresponding stage.

Here's the query I am using now -

```
 SELECT r.so, rd.lastSeen, rd.stage, r.sotype, MAX(rd.lastSeen) as last
            FROM repairs r
            JOIN repair_details rd ON r.id = rd.rid
            WHERE `enddate` IS NULL 
            GROUP BY r.so
            ORDER BY lastSeen asc
```

Any assistance as to how this could be done with one query would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
SELECT a.id, b.stage, b.lastSeen
FROM Return a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT rid, stage, MAX(lastSeen) AS lastSeen FROM Return_Details GROUP BY rid, stage) b ON b.rid = a.id
WHERE a.endDate IS NULL
```

**Edit 1:**

This method will find the `MAX(id)` for each `rid`, then get the details based off that `MAX(id)`.

```
SELECT a.orderNum, c.stage, c.lastSeen
FROM repairs a 
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT rid, MAX(id) AS id FROM repair_details 
    GROUP BY rid) b ON b.rid = a.id
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT id, stage, lastSeen FROM repair_details) c ON c.id = b.id
WHERE a.endDate IS NULL
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d68b/1)

Comment: This is close, however I was not wanting to group by stage since I was hoping to determine `stage` and `lastSeen` for the last occurrence of each `rid`

Currently when I remove the "GROUP BY stage" I go back to getting the same results I was originally getting before where the stage outputted is not the actual current stage but the original stage.

Comment: @Eric is `MAX(id)` equivalent to `MAX(lastSeen)` for an `rid` in `Return_Details` ?

Comment: @Eric I've modified my query. Would you mind trying the modified version?